# Confluent Kafka Azure blob source storage connector error_code": 500, Failed to find any class that implements Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, azure-blob-storage

I have two queries -
1- I'm trying to send data from Azure Blob to Kafka with Azure blob source confluent connector. I'm using Confluent platform version 6.0.1. I have completed all perquisites but when I connect connector I got below error.

"error_code": 500,
"message": "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.AzureBlobStorageSourceConnector.

I installed connecter manually as well as with confluent-hub but getting same error.

2- My goal is, sending data from azure blob to Google big query so my planning is to use Azure blob source connector and google big query sink connector on the same server with kafka and zookeeper.
Can someone please help me if my approach is right or let me know any other good practice for this.
Also, please let me know pipeline how I can configure this.

Comment: Most likely its a jar issue , replace the jar and restart the kafka connect service.

Comment: my connector configuration is like below-   
name=azure-blob-storage-source
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.AzureBlobStorageSourceConnector

azblob.account.name=xxxx
azblob.account.key=xxxx
azblob.container.name=xxx
format.class=io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.format.avro.AvroFormat
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
transforms=AddPrefix
transforms.AddPrefix.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.AddPrefix.regex=.*
transforms.AddPrefix.replacement=copy_of_$0

Comment: Did you download the jars from the confluent hub platform as this connector is not natively available in the default confluent package?. You would have to either download using the confluent command in the confluent cli or place the jars under a folder in `confluent/share/` directory and then restart the confluent platform

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage-source/current/index.html#quick-start
steps to download: https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage-source

Comment: Note: _The Kafka Connect Azure Blob Storage Source Connector provides the capability to read data exported to Azure Blob Storage **by the Kafka Connect Azure Blob Storage Sink Connector**_ ... In other words, if these are your own, random, Blob Storage files, then that connector wont work for this use case

Comment: @OneCricketeer is right but you can overcome this by renaming the files based on the default partitioner naming convention as followed by the azure blob storage sink.